# What is a proper function?

Tags: functions, notation

I search on the Internet for what a proper function is but cannot find anything very related. Wikipedia has definitions about proper convex function and proper concave function but I don't know whether they are the same as proper functions or not?

What is a proper function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map

Comment: Try "proper map" instead.  Inverse images of compact sets should be compact.

Comment: @B.Goddard Is the topological concept of "proper map" related (other than, perhaps, accidentally) with the concept of "proper convex function"?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli  I don't think so.  "Proper" is like "normal" in math.  It has lots of definitions.  Usually, "proper" means that the "or equal to" is removed from the concept.  That's the sense for "proper convex function."  But I don't see that with "proper map."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to search for 'proper map' instead in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map). The simple version is:

> In mathematics, a function between topological spaces is called proper if inverse images of compact subsets are compact. In algebraic geometry, the analogous concept is called a proper morphism.